# What is the best way to create own Ranking Tiers in a ELO system

Tags: ranking, rank, points, tiers

Suppose all Players start with a Score of 1000 Points, how should i create specific Ranking Tiers Like silver/gold/Diamond. How do Games Like Rocket League calculate the ELO Points needed for certain ranks e.g 1000-1100 silver 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with percentages.

F.e. if I win a game, I get 10 points, when I lose, I lose 5-7 points. Then get all points of all players in that server, an f.e. the top 10% are platin, the top 25% gold, the top 50% silver and the rest bronze or something like that. Of course this would need a big playerbase.

Or you could just do it like in League of Legends, but in a different way. Everyone starts at Bronze (lowest rank), and needs 100 points to get to the next elo (or something like that). That is (in my opinion) the fairest ranking system. Winning gives you 10 points, losing leads to losing 5-7 points.

Comment: Percentages wont work for my case because the Playerbase is too small. All Player would be the best rank. And what If a Diamond ist playing against a silver? Should he still earn 25 Points AS in League of Legends or nothing ? I mean in such a small Playerbase i cant Match silvers only With silvers.

Comment: Interesting. You could count how much Elos the enemy is over him (f.e. you are silver and play against platin that means 2 Elo difference), and divide the points the platin player would get (f.e. 10) with that number. That means the higher he is, the less points he loses. You could also divide that Elo difference with the loss of the silver player, so he would not lose too much